# Can't add Australia external bank account ('AUD', 'AU') to Stripe Custom Connect account with US as country and USD as currency

Tags: c#, typescript, stripe-payments

**QUESTION** - How do I add another Stripe external bank account, with a different currency and country than the values used when the Connect account was created? What I'm doing below is causing an error!

**PROBLEM** - Initially the Custom Connect account was set up with US as the country and USD as the currency. The external bank account attached to the Connect account has the same country(US) and currency(USD). I tested a 'no_account' payout failure using a test account from the [Stripe page](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/testing#account-numbers) and the payout failed as expected. Now I want to add another external bank account to complete the payout, but I only have another account in Australia, not the US and not in USD, it's in country code 'AU' and currency code 'AUD'.

**What I tried** - I created a new token in Stripe JS with an Australian account and routing number, AU as the country and AUD as the currency. Received the token, then passed it to my server where I called the ExternalAccountService create() method, but received an error.

**Error message server side** -

> "Invalid currency: aud. You can use these currencies for transfers for an account in US: usd"

```js
// client side
const accountParams = {
  account_number: '000123456'
  country: 'AU'
  currency: 'aud'
  routing_number: '110000'
};

this.stripeService.createToken('bank_account', accountParams).subscribe((result) => {
  if (result.token) {
    if (accountType === 'bank_account') {
      this.updateExternalAccount(result.token.id);
    } else {
      this.updateAccount(result.token.id, false);
    }
  } else if (result.error) {
    this.alertService.danger(result.error.message);
    this.loadingAccount = false;
  }
}, error => {
  console.log(error);
});


// server side
try {
  StripeConfiguration.ApiKey = _config["StripeSettings:SecretKey"];
  var options = new ExternalAccountCreateOptions();
  options.ExternalAccount = updateStripeDto.Token;
  options.DefaultForCurrency = true;

  var service = new ExternalAccountService();
  var newExternalAccount = await service.CreateAsync(stripeAccount.AccountId, options);
} catch (StripeException ex) {
  _logger.LogWarning(ex, ex.StripeError.Message);
  return BadRequest(new ApiResponse(400, "Error creating external account. " + ex.StripeError.Message));
}
```

Comment: Did you try to open a support ticket about this with Stripe?

Comment: They said I have to reverse all transfers for that payout and create new transfers to a different Connect account. That's fucked! Too laborious...

Answer (score 0):

AUD isn't a supported settlement currency that a US based Stripe account supports. You can visit this [page](https://stripe.com/docs/payouts#supported-accounts-and-settlement-currencies) to view the supported settlement currencies supported in various countries.

Comment: if I try and use USD as the currency when creating the token, I get this error message: "Invalid bank account currency for AU-based bank account: USD"

Comment: If you select US as your Stripe account country, you'll see the table indicates that settlement currency USD can only be paid out to to banks in USA.

Comment: So basically I'm f*cked! I can't be the first person who has tested this scenario? If I have only 1 bank account here in the US and the payout fails, how do I add a new account if I don't have a second account in the US? What if my second bank account is in Germany? I can't add it to the connect account to get my payouts? So basically this payout will never be paid to me (the user)?